# Can I use the normal desert background image in Mojave dark mode?

Tags: mojave, dark-mode

I like most of dark mode in Mojave, however I much prefer the light mode 'desert' image to the blue-grey one that appears in dark mode. Is there a way I can use the light mode image when I turn on dark mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Also you can use the dynamic mode where the image is changing according to the clock time of the macbook. [image: Dynamic Settings]
The wallpaper can be change independently on top of the mode that you are working on.